# asp.net frameworks and libraries every developer should know...and use

Tags: asp.net, frameworks

I'm still kinda new in ASP.NET and recently I found out about SubSonic, which I started to use. Now it seems funny and such a waste of time (and nerves) when I look back into times when I was developing without SubSonic and jQuery. And there probably are a lot of libraries and frameworks that speeds up development. Which ones do you use?

Answer (score 1):

What I like to use, at the moment:

- NHibernate
- Autofac
- ASP.NET MVC
- jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I only started liking to make websites once I started using the [MVC Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx)
If you're not already doing this, be sure to check [Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/)'s log. He's the father of SubSonic and recently started working for MS in the MVC team.